# change Month format from jDateChooser

Tags: java, swing, simpledateformat, jdatechooser

how to change month format in jDateChooser ? 
this is my code :

```
    private DateFormat df = DateFormat.getDateInstance();

    private void jButtonInsertActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) { 
            String x = df.format(jDateChooser.getDate());
            showtable(x); // this method for showing Date to jTable 
    }
```

example output : 04 Mar 15, and I want to change Month name "Mar" to "03", but don't know how to change it. Please help

Comment: You have to change the pattern of `df`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the SimpleDataFormat class instead

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Replace this

```
private DateFormat df = DateFormat.getDateInstance();
```

with this

```
private SimpleDateFormat df = SimpleDateFormat("dd MM yy");
```

You can customise any format you want here